# Why is hot reload not working in Flame game engine?

Tags: flutter, flame

I have the component below added to a `FlameGame` class, whenever I am changing this component I have to hot restart the app. Is there a workaround for this?

```
class SoldierSprite extends SpriteAnimationComponent {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {

    var miniSprites =
        await TexturePackerLoader.fromJSONAtlas('mini.png', 'mini.json');

    var miniSpriteComponent = SpriteComponent()
      ..sprite = miniSprites[4]
      ..size = Vector2(100, 200)
      ..position += Vector2(200, 200)
      ..angle = -95;

    add(miniSpriteComponent);

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hot reload only works for changes in the widget tree.

Since your game lives within the `GameWidget`, Flutter can't know that it has changed if you don't update for example the `key` in the `GameWidget` when you do a hot reload.

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered this problem and noticed that hot reloading ***does*** work when you wrap your GameWidget inside a non GameWidget, e.g.:

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Game'),
      ),
      body: GameWidget(
        game: MyGame(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

where `MyGame` is

```
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  ...
}
```